# About installation and formatting hard drive

Tags: system-installation, hard-drive

I do have a 500gb hard drive where I made 3 partitions.
The c drive contains the windows..and other drives contain documents..so if i clean install ubuntu will it only delete the c drive where my Windows is or the entire 500gb? It is very important..please help me. I have tried ubuntu but not sure about installation.

Comment: It will ask you what you would like to do during the installation.  To answer your question more accurately, you'll have to explain what you would like to occur.

Comment: It will wipe the entire disk clean if you do an "erase and install". The "something else" can be used to specify different. You want to keep your Windows, and set up a dual-boot configuration. Please edit your question to include a screenshot of gparted so I can make a better further recommendation. Cheers, Al

Comment: I only want to clear my primary partition where the windows is installed not the entire hard drive..is it possible to choose that primary partition only?

Comment: Are you sure that you want to get rid of Windows? How are you going to do things like BIOS updates, or run Windows-only apps? In **ANY** case, I'd always recommend backing up your important data, just in case something goes wrong. The "something else" install should work for you. Cheers, Al

Comment: What format are your other 2 partitions? Any reason to have 2, vs 1? NTFS? Cheers, Al

Comment: But it shows "System program problem detected" when I am using live usb..and not showing the entire desktop

Comment: That's a new problem. It's probably a bad build of the USB flash. If you have a DVD on the machine, burning the .iso to DVD and then booting off of DVD will ALWAYS work better. Please see my previous question about your other 2 partitions, and post a gparted screenshot, as requested. Cheers, Al

Comment: While nstalling windows it showed NTFS

Comment: Screenshot? Cheers, Al

Comment: Cant take e screenshot either..

Comment: If you boot the Ubuntu Live DVD, or a working Ubuntu USB flash, you can. Cheers, Al

Comment: No, live usb not working properly..it shows nothing except the desktop wallpaper